# Making a new line in a file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Im trying to write a text to file, but it overwrites whats inside, can somebody explain how to check if the text exists and then put a new line and write? Here is the code I am working with:

```
try
{
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw =
        new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write(petName);
    bw.close();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
catch (IOException exc)
{
    System.out.println(exc);
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to check if the text exists and then put a new line and write?

Use [File#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) to check if the text exists in the file.

```
if(file.length()>0){
    bw.newLine();
}
```

**Note:** 
Open the file in append mode if you don't want to override the existing content of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Use following to append if file exists.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Comment: how to check if the text exists and then put a new line and write?

Comment: It will not prevent to put the new line at the beginning if file is created first time.